# How to Create a Global Level Function with UI capability

Tags: android, function, global

I have a function to find an employee's id number from my sqlite database.  The function allows the user to look up by id or name (first and/or last); therefore it creates several dialog boxes and finds the data through an If Else Then tree.  Here's the code for those who like that sort of thing:

```
public String getEmployeeID() {
  final CharSequence[] items = {"By ID", "By Name", "Cancel"};
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LibraryScreen.this);
  builder.setTitle("Find Employee");
  builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
      if(items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
        dialog.cancel();
        empid = "";
      } else if(items[item].equals("By ID")) {
        dialog.cancel();
        final Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(LibraryScreen.this);
        dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.peopledialog);
        dialog2.setTitle("Employee ID");
        dialog2.setCancelable(true);
        //Set Visibility of the Rows
        TableRow tblrow1 = (TableRow) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.trGeneral);
        tblrow1.setVisibility(0);
        //Set Captions for Rows
        TextView txtvw1 = (TextView)  dialog2.findViewById(R.id.tvGeneral);
        txtvw1.setText("Employee ID");
        //Set Up Edit Text Boxes
        EditText edttxt1 = (EditText) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.txtGeneral);
        //Set Input Type
        edttxt1.setRawInputType(0x00000002);//numbers
        edttxt1.setText("");
        //set max lines
        edttxt1.setMaxLines(1);
        //Set MaxLength
        int maxLength;
        maxLength = 15;
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
        edttxt1.setFilters(FilterArray);
        Button button = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.btnTxtDiaSav);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText emplid = (EditText) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.txtGeneral);
            String newemp = "";
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getEmployee(emplid.getText().toString());
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
              empid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("employeeid"));
            } else {
              Toast.makeText(LibraryScreen.this, "No ID Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              empid = "";
            }
            c.close();
            db.close();
            dialog2.dismiss();
          }
        });
        Button buttonCan = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.btnTxtDiaCan);
        buttonCan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog2.dismiss();
            empid = "";
          }
        });
        dialog2.show();

      } else if(items[item].equals("By Name")) {
        dialog.cancel();
        final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(LibraryScreen.this);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.peopledialog);
        dialog1.setTitle("Employee's Name");
        dialog1.setCancelable(true);
        //Set Visibility of the Rows
        TableRow tblrow1 = (TableRow) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.trGeneral);
        tblrow1.setVisibility(0);
        //Set Captions for Rows
        TextView txtvw1 = (TextView)  dialog1.findViewById(R.id.tvGeneral);
        txtvw1.setText("Employee Name");
        //Set Up Edit Text Boxes
        EditText edttxt1 = (EditText) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.txtGeneral);
        //Set Input Type
        edttxt1.setRawInputType(0x00002001);//cap words
        edttxt1.setText("");
        //set max lines
        edttxt1.setMaxLines(1);
        //Set MaxLength
        int maxLength;
        maxLength = 50;
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
        edttxt1.setFilters(FilterArray);

        Button button = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btnTxtDiaSav);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText emplid = (EditText) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.txtGeneral);
            String firstname = emplid.getText().toString();
            String lastname = "";
            String matchlist = "";
            String temptext = "";
            int matchcount = 0;
            if(firstname.lastIndexOf(" ") <= 0) {
              lastname = firstname;
              firstname = "X";
            } else {
              lastname = firstname.substring(firstname.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
              firstname = firstname.substring(0, firstname.lastIndexOf(" "));
            }
            db.open();
            Cursor c1, c2;
            String titletext = "";
            if(firstname.length() > 0) {
              c1 = db.getEmployeeByName(lastname, firstname);
              if(c1.getCount() == 0) {
                c1 = db.getRowByFieldTextOrdered("employees", "lastname", lastname, "lastname, firstname");
                if(c1.getCount() == 0) {
                  Toast.makeText(LibraryScreen.this, "No matching Employees.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  empid = "";
                }
              }
              if(c1.getCount() > 0) {
                do {
                  c2 = db.getRowByField("orgcodes", "manager", c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("employeeid")));
                  if(c2.moveToFirst()) {
                    if(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("orgcode")).substring(9, 10).equals("0")) {
                      if(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("orgcode")).substring(7, 8).equals("0")) {
                        if(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("orgcode")).substring(5, 6).equals("0")) {
                          if(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("orgcode")).substring(4, 5).equals("0")) {
                            if(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("orgcode")).substring(3, 4).equals("0")) {
                              titletext = "Top Brass";
                            } else {
                              titletext = "Senior VP";
                            }
                          } else {
                            titletext = "VP";
                          }
                        } else {
                          titletext = "Director";
                        }
                      } else {
                        titletext = "Senior Manager";
                      }
                    } else {
                      titletext = "Manager";
                    }
                  } else {
                    titletext = "Employee";
                  }
                  matchcount++;
                  matchlist = matchlist + c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("employeeid")) + ": " + c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("firstname")) + " " + c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("lastname")) + ": " + titletext + "|";
                } while(c1.moveToNext());
              }
            } else {
              empid = "";
            }
            if(matchcount == 0) {
              db.close();
              Toast.makeText(LibraryScreen.this, "No matching Employees.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              empid = "";
            } else {
              final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[matchcount + 1];
              items[0] = "(Cancel)";
              for(int i = 1; i <= matchcount; i++) {
                items[i] = matchlist.substring(0, matchlist.indexOf("|"));
                matchlist = matchlist.substring(matchlist.indexOf("|") + 1);
              }
              db.close();
              AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(LibraryScreen.this);
              builder1.setTitle("Select Employee");
              builder1.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                  if(items[item].equals("(Cancel)")) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    empid = "";
                  } else {
                    String wasted = items[item].toString();
                    empid = wasted.substring(0, wasted.indexOf(":"));
                    dialog.cancel();
                  }
                }
              });
              AlertDialog alert1 = builder1.create();
              alert1.show();
            }
            dialog1.dismiss();
          }
        });
        Button buttonCan = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btnTxtDiaCan);
        buttonCan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog1.dismiss();
            empid = "";
          }
        });
        dialog1.show();
      }
    }
  });
  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  alert.show();
  return empid;
}
```

I use the employee id for a variety of functions through multiple activities in my program.  Up to now, I've simply pasted the code under each listener that needs the id, but that is such a waste of space IMHO.

My question:

Is there a way to put this function somewhere that can be called from many different activities?

If so:

1. How do I do that?
2. How do I set the context for the dialog boxes for multiple activities?
3. How do I get the employee id back to the function that needs it?

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find it online: actually, I'm not even sure how to word the query right.  My attempts have come up woefully short.

Comment: Well you could create a base activity and put your function in their. And make the rest of the activities extend the base activity. That would solve question 1.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party - but recorded for posterity:

Read up on the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class:

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
>   You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class
>   to be instantiated for you when the process for your
>   application/package is created.

Basically, this would give you the ability to obtain a single object that represents your running application (think of it as a singleton that returns an instance of your running app).

You first start off by creating a class that extends Application base class and defining any common code that is used throughout your application

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

       public void myGlobalBusinessLogic() {
           //
       }   
}
```

Then tell your application to use the `MyApplication` class instead of the default `Application` class via the `<application>` node in your app manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="MyApplication">
```

Finally, when you need to get to your common function just do something like:

```
MyApplication application =  (MyApplication) getApplication();

application.myGlobalBusinessLogic();
```

If you need to get the context from any part of your application, you can simple return it by calling `getApplicationContext()` (defined in the base `Application` class) via a getter method within your custom application class.